# Регулярные запросы на сервер Kotlin Android

Tags: android, kotlin

Возникла необходимость отправлять регулярные запросы на сервер в фоне. Как это можно лучше всего сделать?

Comment: непонятен вопрос, уточните его пожалуйста

Comment: Retrofit + WorkManager.